# Trouble converting string to time

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I have an alarm program that accepts a user input in a tkinter GUI then I try to store that input as a time datatype. I am having trouble converting the string to time.

```
a.setAlarm( time.strptime(e.get(), "%H:%M") )
e.delete(0, END)
print(a.getAlarmTime())
```

a is an instance of my class Alarm. e is an instance of the tkinter class Entry.

In the `setAlarm(alarm_time)` function, I have the following:

```
if type(alarm_time) is time:
    self.alarm_time = alarm_time
    print('It\'s a time!')
else:
    print('It\'s not a time!')
```

Comment: _"I am having trouble"_ - what sort of trouble are you having? What is the code doing that is different from what you expect.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error? We can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question. At this moment I have not idea what is your problem. Maybe better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run. And show example data which makes problem and full error message

Comment: preferred `if isinstance(alarm_time, time):` but real problem can be that `time` is module name, not type. and it has to be `isinstance(alarm_time, time.struct_time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your real problem but I see one mistake:

`time` is NOT type, but module's name.

If you run

```
print( type( time.strptime("12:00", "%H:%M") ) )
```

then you see real type

```
<class 'time.struct_time'>
```

and you should use `time.struct_time` instead of `time` like

```
#if type(alarm_time) is time.struct_time:
if isinstance(alarm_time, time.struct_time):
    self.alarm_time = alarm_time
    print("It's a time!")
else:
    print("It's not a time!")
```